# Server-side validation for newly created rows in a Kendo grid (in-cell, batch editing mode)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I have a Kendo Grid with `InCell` editing that sends created/updated records to the server in batches (`.Batch(true)`).

Here's a pared-down example of the grid definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TagEditingGridViewModel>()
    .Name("...")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(e => e.TagText);
        c.Bound(e => e.Description);
    })
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Model(m => m.Id(e => e.ID))
        //.Events(e => e.Error("...").RequestEnd("..."))
        // Read, Update, Create actions
    )
)
```

The grid handles `Tag` items, which must have a unique, non-empty value in the `TagText` property.

Here's the grid's model class, with its validation attributes:

```csharp
public class TagEditingGridViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "A tag text is required.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Text cannot be longer than 50 characters")]
    public string TagText { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 250 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The `[StringLength]` attribute triggers client-side validation, as does the `[Required]` attribute when the field is empty. But server-side validation is still needed when the `TagText` field is whitespace only, and to check uniqueness.

This server-side validation needs to take place both on updating an existing record and on creating a new record. That's where the problem begins. For an existing record, the model has an `ID` in the database that can be used to find the corresponding row in the grid. But a *new* record that does not pass validation does not get an `ID` in the database and does not have a (unique) `ID` in the grid rows - it is set to `0`, so you can't identify a row from that property.

In [this post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-would-i-highlight-the-grid-row-cell-that-contained-an-element-with-a-server-side-validation-error-in-a-kendo-grid-with-incell-and-batch-editing#2786099) in the Kendo forums, a Telerik employee has posted a solution to showing a server-side validation error in a Kendo grid with `InCell` and batch editing. Unfortunately, they only show the solution on update, not on create.

In their suggested solution, they use the `onError` event of the grid's DataSource, where they find the the row in the grid using the model's ID field.

```
// Controller:
currentErrors.Add(new Error() { id = model.LookupId, errors = errorMessages });

// JavaScript:
var item = dataSource.get(error.id);
var row = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + item.uid + "']");
```

In my create action, I loop through the incoming items and set the key in the model state dictionary to "`models[i].TagText`". When the `TagText` is a string that only contains whitespace, the `[Required]` attribute catches this server-side, and adds a model state error in that same format.

```
// items: List<TagEditingGridViewModel>

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
{
    // check for uniqueness of TagText ...
    
    // this is the way the validation attributes do it
    ModelState.AddModelError($"models[{i}].TagText", "Tag text must be unique.");
}

return Json(items.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In my grid, I can add a handler to the `RequestEnd` event, which has access to the request type (read, create, or update), the data sent back from the server (which would be `items`), and any model state errors.

But I still have the problem that I'm not able to map items with an ID of 0 to rows in the grid. Is there any guarantee that the `items` are still in the same order they were sent, and that that is the order they are in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving this issue:

1. I first modified my grid view model to include a property for the Kendo grid row's UID.

   ```cs
   public string KendoRowUID { get; set; }
   ```
2. I added two events to the grid's `DataSource` (not to the grid as a whole).
   In the `Change` event, when the action was `"add"` (when a new row is added), I set the data item's `KendoRowUID` property to the row's UID.

   ```cs
   .DataSource(d => d
       // ...
       .Events(e => e
           .Change("grdEditTagsOnChange")
           .Error("grdEditTagsOnError")     // explained in step 7
       )
   )
   ```

   ```js
   function grdEditTagsOnChange(e) {
       // set the KendoRowUID field in the datasource object to the row uid attribute
       if (e.action == "add" && e.items.length) {
           var item = e.items[0];
           item.KendoRowUID = item.uid;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Based on what information I needed to show the `ModelState` errors on the page, I created this method in my controller. It simply takes the fields I needed and sticks them into a JSON object string that I can later deserialize in JavaScript.
   I added all `ModelState` errors under the key `""`, so that later (step 7), they all show up under `e.errors[""]`.

   ```cs
   private void AddGridModelError(string field, string message, 
                                  string kendoRowUid, int? modelId = null)
   {   
       var error = new {    
           field,    
           message, 
           kendoRowUid,
           modelId = (modelId != null && modelId > 0) ? modelId : null 
       };
       ModelState.AddModelError("", 
           // Newtonsoft.Json
           JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error, Formatting.None));
   }
   ```
4. I created this method to modify any existing `ModelState` errors to fit the new format. This is necessary because the `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` attribute *does* catch empty strings, but only server-side (empty strings don't get caught in client-side validation).
   (This may not be the most efficient or best way to do it, but it works.)

   ```cs
   private void AlterModelError(List<TagEditingGridViewModel> items)
   {
       // stick them in this list (not straight in ModelState)
       // so can clear existing errors out of the modelstate easily
       var newErrors = new List<(string, string, string, int)>();

       // get existing model state errors
       var modelStateErrors = ModelState.Where(ms => ms.Key != "" && ms.Value.Errors.Any());
       foreach (var mse in modelStateErrors)
       {
           // the validation attributes do it like this: "models[0].TagText"
           if (mse.Key.Contains('.'))
           {
               var split = mse.Key.Split('.');
               if (split.Length == 2)
               {
                   // get index from "models[i]" part
                   var regex = new Regex(@"models\[(\d+)\]");
                   var match = regex.Match(split[0]);

                   var index = match.Groups[1].Value?.ToInt();
                   if (index != null)
                   {
                       var item = items[index.Value];
                       foreach (var err in mse.Value.Errors)
                       {
                           newErrors.Add((split[1], err.ErrorMessage, item.KendoRowUID, item.ID));
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       // clear everything from the model state, and add new-format errors
       ModelState.Clear();
       foreach (var item in newErrors)
       {
           // call the method shown in step 3:
           AddGridModelError(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3, item.Item4);
       }
   }
   ```
5. In the create/update grid actions, I call the `AlterModelError` method if there are any `ModelState` errors already present. And did additional validation as necessary.

   ```cs
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       AlterModelError(items);
   }

   // 'item' is type: TagEditingGridViewModel
   AddGridModelError(
       nameof(TagEditingGridViewModel.TagText), 
       "The tag text must be unique.", 
       item.KendoRowUID, 
       item.ID);
   ```
6. At the end of the create/update grid actions, I made sure to include the `ModelState` dictionary when calling `ToDataSourceResult`:

   ```cs
   return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   ```
7. Finally, in the grid's `DataSource`'s `Error` event, I ...

   - Check if there are any errors in the event `errors` property
   - Add a one-time handler to the grid's `DataSource` sync event
   - In that sync event handler, loop through all the errors, and
   - Parse the string into a JSON object
   - Find the `<tr>` row.
     If the item already exists in the database, its `ID` field can be used to get the item from the `DataSource`, and the row can be gotten from there. If the item was a newly created item, its `ID` is still set to `0`, so the `kendoRowUid` property of the JSON object is used.
   - Use the `field` property of the JSON object to locate the correct column (and thus, cell) within the row
   - Append an element to the cell that shows the validation message

   ```js
   function grdEditTagsOnError(e) {
     // if there are any errors
     if (e.errors && e.errors[""]?.errors.length) {
       var grid = $("#grdEditTags").data("kendoGrid");

       // e.sender is the dataSource
       // add a one-time handler to the "sync" event
       e.sender.one("sync", function (e) {

         // loop through the errors
         e.errors[""].errors.forEach(err => {
           // try to parse error message (custom format) to a json object
           var errObj = JSON.parse(err);

           if (errObj) {
             if (errObj.kendoRowUid) {
               // find row by uid
               var row = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + errObj.kendoRowUid + "']");
             } else if (errObj.modelId) {
               // find row by model id
               var dsItem = grid.dataSource.get(errObj.modelId);
               var row = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + dsItem.uid + "']");
             }

             // if the row was found
             if (row && row.length) {
               // find the index of the column
               var column = null;
               for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
                 if (grid.columns[i].field == errObj.field) {
                   column = i;
                 }
               }

               if (column != null) {
                 // get the <td> cell
                 var cell = row.find("td:eq(" + column + ")");
                 if (cell) {
                   // create the validation message
                   // in the same format as the grid's default validation elements
                   var valMessage =
                     '<div class="k-tooltip k-tooltip-error k-validator-tooltip k-invalid-msg field-validation-error" ' +
                          'data-for="' + errObj.field + '" ' +
                          'id="' + errObj.field + '_validationMessage" ' +
                          'data-valmsg-for="' + errObj.field + '">' +
                       '<span class="k-tooltip-icon k-icon k-i-warning"></span>' +
                       '<span class="k-tooltip-content">' + errObj.message + '</span>' +
                       '<span class="k-callout k-callout-n"></span>' +                         
                     '</div>';

                   // insert validation message after
                   cell.html(cell.html() + valMessage);

                   // make the message not cut off
                   cell.css("overflow", "visible");

                 }  // end 'if (cell)'
               }  // end 'if (column != null)'
             }  // end 'if (row && row.length)'
           }  // end 'if (errObj)'
         });// end 'errors.forEach'
       });// end 'e.sender.one("sync", function ...'
     }  // end if any errors
   }  // end function
   ```